# Complex query - retrieve employees working in both two specific departments

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to figure a way to retrieve employees working in two different departments.

I have 3 simple tables:

- employee (employee_id, employee_name)
- department (department_id, department_name)
- working (eid, did, work_time)

So I have tried to write a SQL query:

```
 select employee_name
 from employee, working,department
 where eid = employee_id 
   and did = department_id 
   and department_name = 'software'
   and dname = 'hardware';
```

But it doesn't work, what is my problem?

Comment: Sample data and desired result would help to help you.

Comment: Do you want employees that work in both departments, or just any of them?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are requiring department to be both 'software' and 'hardware'. Also, dname is not a field.

Correcting your query:

```
select employee_name
from employee, working, department
where eid = employee_id and did = department_id 
and (department_name = 'software' or department_name = 'hardware');
```

But I would prefer this kind of query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.employee_name
FROM employee e
JOIN working w ON w.eid = e.employee_id
JOIN department d ON d.department_id = w.did
WHERE d.department_name IN ('software', 'hardware');
```

That is to get employees that work in any of the two departments (or both).

If you want only employees that work in both departments, try this:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.employee_name
FROM employee e
JOIN working w ON w.eid = e.employee_id
JOIN department d ON d.department_id = w.did
WHERE d.department_name IN ('software', 'hardware')
GROUP BY e.employee_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.department_id) = 2;
```

Comment: This will not "retrieve an employee working in two different departments"; it will find all employees working in either the software or hardware (or both) departments (so the majority of rows will probably be employees working in a single department).

Comment: thank you for responding , so that mean it's impossible to retrieve an employee working in two different departments?

Comment: @Ammar I added a query to get employees that work in both departments. Try it.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is redundant with a `GROUP BY`. You need to `COUNT` something. If two employees have the same name then you will aggregate them together.

Comment: You final query will error with `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`. If you fix that, it would then find employees who have 2 working entries in the `software` department and 0 entries in the `hardware` department.

Comment: @MT0 Edited to avoid 2 working entries in the software department and 0 entries in the hardware department.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily obtain employees who work in one specific department:

```
select *
  from Employee e inner join
       Working w on e.employee_id = w.eid inner join
       Department d on w.did = d.department_id
 where d.name = 'software'
```

Now ambiguity cames. If you want to get all employees work *either* in `software` *or* in `hardware`:

```
-- Employees who work at either software or hardware or both departments
select *
  from Employee e inner join
       Working w on e.employee_id = w.eid inner join
       Department d on w.did = d.department_id
 where d.name = in ('software', 'hardware')
```

If you want to get employees who works in *both* `software` **and** `hardware` departments:

```
-- Employees who work in both hardware and software deparments simultaneously 
select *
  from Employee e inner join
       Working w on e.employee_id = w.eid inner join
       Department d on w.did = d.department_id
 where d.name = 'software'

intersect

select *
  from Employee e inner join
       Working w on e.employee_id = w.eid inner join
       Department d on w.did = d.department_id
 where d.name = 'hardware'
```

Comment: thank you for responding , that command will retrieve all record for an employee who works in 2 departments or more , right? , I need to retrieve an employee name that works in two specific departments , if Im wrong correct me and srry

Comment: @Ammar: do you want to obtain employees who work in *both* specific departments (e. g. John Smith who works in software **and** hardware) or employees who work in *at least one* of specific department either `software` **or** `hardware` **or** in both?

Answer (score 0):

> What is my problem?

There is no `dname` column in your tables.

---

You can simplify the problem as you don't need the `department` table since the `working` table contains the department id in the `did` column.

Then you need to `GROUP BY` each employee and find those `HAVING` a `COUNT` of two `DISTINCT` department ids:

```sql
SELECT MAX(e.employee_name)
FROM   employee e
       INNER JOIN working w
       ON e.employee_id = w.eid
GROUP BY e.employee_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.did) = 2
```

If you want to consider only the `software` and `hardware` departments then:

```sql
SELECT MAX(e.employee_name)
FROM   employee e
       INNER JOIN working w
       ON e.employee_id = w.eid
       INNER JOIN department d
       ON w.did = d.department_id
WHERE  d.department_name IN ('software', 'hardware')
GROUP BY e.employee_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT w.did) = 2
```

Comment: Why MAX(e.employee_name) ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Because the `GROUP BY` is on the `e.employee_id` primary key and `employee_name` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause so must be in an aggregation function (or included in the `GROUP BY` but that is not preferable).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
SELECT
   count(*) as cnt,
   employee.employee_name
FROM
   employee
   JOIN working ON working.eid = employee.employee_id
   JOIN department ON department.department_id = working.did
WHERE
   department.department_name = 'software' or department.department_name = 'hardware'
GROUP BY employee.employee_name
HAVING cnt > 1
```

This would count each employee who is linked both software or hardware department. Or you can leave WHERE clause away to get all employees working more than one departments.